# Probability that X is greater than the mode of X?

Tags: probability-distributions

How do I solve this problem:

Let X be a continuous random variable with density function
\begin{equation}
f(x) =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill ax^2e^{-10x}    \hfill & \text{for x $\geq$ 0} \\
      \hfill 0 \hfill & \text{otherwise} \\
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where a > 0. What is the probability of X greater than or equal to the mode of X?

Comment: What have you done so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I got stuck in integrating $$\int_{0}^{\infty} ax^2e^{-10x} dx = 1$$ and onwards.

Comment: @Ralf17 Good idea. Apply the method of integration by parts with $ u=x^2, v'=e^{-10x}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What is the probability of $X$ greater than or equal to the mode of $X$?*

**Hint**. One may find the maximum of $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$, using
\begin{equation}
f'(x) =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill -2ax(5x-1)e^{-10x}    \hfill & \text{for $x \geq$ 0} \\\\
      \hfill 0. \hfill & \text{otherwise} \\
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then one may evaluate
$$
P\left(X\geq \frac15\right)=\int_{1/5}^\infty-2ax(5x-1)e^{-10x}\:dx.
$$ The latter integral may be computed by parts.